# Why was Slovakia relegated to the IIHF C category in 1993?

Tags: ice-hockey, relegations, iihf

Why was [Slovakia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slovakia_men%27s_national_ice_hockey_team) relegated to the IIHF C category in 1993? Was it only because the Czechs were the official successors of Czechoslovakia? Why weren't the Slovaks? Were there any official steps the Slovakian team could have taken to remain in the A Category?

Answer (score 1):

Team Slovakia was not relegated. They actually participated as a new team with Belarus, Croatia, and Estonia. These four new participants were all assigned to Group C1.

If you compare rosters of 1993 Czech, 1994 Czech, and 1994 Slovakia, most of Team Czech in 1993 moved to Team Czech in 1994.

Among 20 forwards and defenses of Team Czech in 1993, 10 members are still in Team Czech in 1993 while none of them are in Team Slovakia in 1994.

Czech roster in 1993: https://www.hhof.com/IZone/izone.country.clubs.national.roster.do?co=CZE&tour=WC&division=MA&yr=1993

Czech roster in 1994: https://www.hhof.com/IZone/izone.country.clubs.national.roster.do?co=CZE&tour=WC&division=MA&yr=1994

Slovakia roster in 1994:
https://www.hhof.com/IZone/izone.country.clubs.national.roster.do?co=SVK&tour=WC&division=MC&yr=1994

Thus, you can say that Team Czech in 1994 is a successor of Team Czech in 1993.

Answer (score -1):

The Czechs were considered to be the successor country and Slovakia a new country and therefore Slovakia was forced to start from the bottom. This was because the majority of the Czechoslovak team was from Czechia.

Comment: Do you have any official documents or references about that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slovakia_men%27s_national_ice_hockey_team

Comment: "While the Czechs were allowed to compete in the highest pool (A), the IIHF ruled that because fewer players of the former Czechoslovak team were Slovaks, Slovakia would be required to start international play in pool C" From the wikipedia which i sent

Comment: Yes, but thats not an official info why it happened, there is just a reference to an old "iihf story" article where nothing is said about the relegation decision. Is there no official document about that decision?